# Insert into table without PK in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm currently using .NET Core 3.1, I want to make Integration some of my data into an existing application. This application is using SQL Server as the database at first I want to use SSIS to integrate my data into this application but I just know that they are using SQL Server Express so I can't use SSIS.

So I decided to create a hangfire job to get my data (multiple sources) and insert it into the existing application using EF Core. But now I just know that the table doesn't have PK since It already running for quite some time and is not my application I can't just add the pk to the table. When I try to Insert it using EF Core I got this error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to track an instance of type 'T1Item' because it does not have a primary key. Only entity types with primary keys may be tracked.'

Here is my code:

```
using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
    var db1 = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<db1Context>();
    var db2 = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<db2Context>();

    var stagingTableConfig = db1 .KreTableFlagConfiguration.Where(x => x.TableName.ToLower() == "kre_productcategory").FirstOrDefault();

    if (stagingTableConfig != null)
    {
        var listProductCategory = db1.KreProductCategory.Where(x => x.Id > stagingTableConfig.LastataIndex).ToList();

        if (listProductCategory.Count > 0)
        {   
            long lastIndex = listProductCategory.Select(x => x.Id).Max();
            stagingTableConfig.LastataIndex = lastIndex;

            List<T1Item> listT1Items = new List<T1Item>();

            foreach (var pc in listProductCategory)
            {
                T1Item t1Item = new T1Item()
                            {
                                TiKd = pc.Category,
                                TiNm = pc.Name,
                                FlagApproval = 0,
                                FlagCleansing = 0,
                                TiKet = pc.Description
                            };

                listT1Items.Add(t1Item);
            }

            db2.T1Item.AddRange(listT1Items);
            db2.SaveChanges();

            db1.KreTableFlagConfiguration.Update(stagingTableConfig);
            db2.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

I wonder if there is a way I can insert it using ef core. Maybe there is another option to using ADO net to insert into a table that using PK. But if I can use EF core I prefer using EF Core.

Edit

```
modelBuilder.Entity<T1Item>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasNoKey();

                entity.ToTable("T1_ITEM");

                entity.Property(e => e.FlagApproval)
                    .HasColumnName("FLAG_APPROVAL")
                    .HasColumnType("numeric(5, 0)");

                entity.Property(e => e.FlagCleansing)
                    .HasColumnName("FLAG_CLEANSING")
                    .HasColumnType("numeric(5, 0)");

                entity.Property(e => e.ItPk)
                    .HasColumnName("IT_PK")
                    .HasColumnType("numeric(10, 0)");

                entity.Property(e => e.TiKd)
                    .HasColumnName("TI_KD")
                    .HasMaxLength(5)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .IsFixedLength();

                entity.Property(e => e.TiKet)
                    .HasColumnName("TI_KET")
                    .HasMaxLength(255)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.TiNm)
                    .HasColumnName("TI_NM")
                    .HasMaxLength(255)
                    .IsUnicode(false);
            });
```

Comment: Where you define T1Satuan?

Comment: I'm sorry I copied the wrong error, but it same error for the T1Satuan and T1Item. when I'm Inserting it

Comment: It's about ``SaveChange``, please see option 2 in my answer

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad I think option 2 is for Net 5.0 only right?  And the error is actually thrown in the AddRange part.

Comment: It might help. https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18116

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Keyless` attribute on youe model or use `HasNoKey` fluent api in ef core like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
modelBuilder
    .Entity<BlogPostsCount>(
        eb =>
        {
            eb.HasNoKey();
            eb.Property(v => v.BlogName).HasColumnName("Name");
        });
}
```

Or for use attribute:

```
[Keyless]
public class BlogPostsCount
{
public string BlogName { get; set; }
public int PostCount { get; set; }
}
```

However, they are different from regular entity types in that they:

**1-** Cannot have a key defined.

**2-** Are never tracked for changes in the DbContext and therefore are never inserted, updated or deleted on the database.

**3-** Are never discovered by convention.
Only support a subset of navigation mapping capabilities, specifically:
They may never act as the principal end of a relationship.

**4-** They may not have navigations to owned entities
They can only contain reference navigation properties pointing to regular entities.

**5-** Entities cannot contain navigation properties to keyless entity types.

**6-** May be mapped to a defining query. A defining query is a query declared in the model that acts as a data source for a keyless entity type.

Comment: Hi I already defined HasNoKey before, but when I'm Inserting I still got the error

Comment: Where you define it? Please update your question

Answer (score 3):

As [Microsoft's docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotationshttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations) state about keyless entities, they

> are never inserted, updated or deleted on the database

because they cannot be tracked. For update or delete this is acceptable, but despite the fact that inserting could work in theory, it does not as of EF Core 7.
We have the same problem with inserting into a log table without a key, and we have to do it with bulk insert or ExecuteSqlRaw.